# Why am I getting errors when trying to push code to scratch org?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, scratch-org, vs-code

I'm trying to `push` my code into a `scratch org` using `SFDX`. I keep getting errors which don't make sense -- many of them are saying how a variable doesn't exist and I scan the class to see the variable declaration and scoping is correct for it to be accessible. Many errors about `custom objects` too.

These are the steps I followed:

```
1. Pull current code from git repo
2. Create SFDX project and set up source org
3. Create assets/package.xml to retrieve data using the following cmd: 
   sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest assets/package.xml
4. Created a scratch org and tried pushing code into scratch org
```

On the push, I received various `variable doesn't exist` and `custom object` errors. What am I missing?

Comment: have you pushed your custom objects into the scratch org? The scratch org will have nothing other than the features activated you set in the configuration file.

Comment: Or to put it another way, does your project include the objects folder with all your custom objects and their fields in it?

Comment: It may be helpful to see the package.xml and maybe one of the error dumps. Usually might be one or a small number of root cause errors, the rest are typically fixed once you fix the root cause error.

Comment: Update - I scanned all my classes and made sure all `custom objects` were being retrieved. Tried deploying to scratch org again after retrieval - still keep getting errors saying `variable does not exist` and `exceeded the allowed number of fields to track on a given entity`. Would a better approach be to retrieve everything from my dev environment?